# How to set camera resolution using intent ?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera-intent

My app is using this Intent to take photos:

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
i.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, saveUri);
startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
```

Is there any way to set the resolution of the camera?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First thing resolution means capturing size i expect, not preview size .. right ??

As if, no you can't do this because you are using default camera activity, if you want to set  by your own you need to write your own custom code where you can set whatever you want. By the way if you are opening default camera activity, I think their it self you can find some option to set the resolution(through menu or surface button) which varies from device to device.

Answer (score -1):

You can not do this using Intent method.

But you can change the resolution, If you use Camera in your own app.

```
 Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
 parameters.setPreviewSize(x, y);
 camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Comment: I don't think resolution is same as the preview size, both are different.